# Why do event handlers not get the right handle to this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I understand the concept of binding event handlers in order for them to get the proper reference to `this`. My question is, why does referencing a class's method not provide it the proper `this`?

Do ES6 classes not automatically provide `this` on class methods?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  clickHandler(event) {
    console.log('this', this);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Button</button>;
  }
}
```

As expected, the above code will print `null` for the value of `this`. However, explicitly calling the handler will give the correct value, i.e. `<button onClick={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />`. Why does the handler have the correct reference to `this` using the arrow function?

I can hypothesize a bunch of answers, but I'd like the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do event handlers not get the right handle to this?

They do! They get a reference to the element you hooked the event on, as normal.

> Do ES6 classes not automatically provide `this` on class methods?

They don't, no; ES2015 ("ES6") classes use the same fundamental prototypical inheritance and `this` assignment as ES5 and before, with different syntax (and a couple of new features).

> However, explicitly calling the handler will give the correct value

Right, for the same reason that in this code, `example` is called with `this` referring to `x`:

```
x.example();
```

...but in this code, `example` is called with `this` being `undefined` (in strict mode; it would be the global object in loose mode):

```
let e = x.example;
e();
```

Using `class` doesn't change the need for `this` management.

To make `this` to refer to the component class, you need to either bind `this` to it, or use an arrow function that closes over the `this` to use:

Binding (a fairly common pattern):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {                               // ***
    super(...args);                                    // ***
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);  // ***
  }                                                    // ***

  clickHandler(event) {
     console.log('this', this);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Button</button>;
  }
}
```

Using an arrow function instead (also fairly common):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  clickHandler = event => {                            // ***
     console.log('this', this);
  };                                                   // ***

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Button</button>;
  }
}
```

That latter option assumes you're transpiling with support for the upcoming [public class fields](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/), which aren't standard yet. (The proposal is [still](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) at [stage 2](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) as of this writing.) Instead of creating a property on the prototype, it creates an instance field with an arrow function, which closes over `this` (which is a reference to the component instance).